# Zend_Loader can't find my file?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-loader

I am following [this tutorial](http://akrabat.com/2008/02/21/simple-zend_form-example/) on Zend Forms.  I copied it verbatim and I got this error

> Fatal error: Class 'forms_ContactForm' not found in /Quickstart/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 10

Which led me to believe it wasn't loading in the class, so I added this into my IndexController.php file

```
Zend_Loader::loadClass('forms_ContactForm');
```

This is the main error I am receiving, I believe it is because it cannot locate my form_ContactForm.php file and I am unsure why.

This is my hierarchy of folders:
Quickstart

   application

      controllers

      forms

      layouts

      views

   library

   public

[link to full error text](http://www.levijackson.net/Quickstart/public/)

Any help would be appreciated,
Levi

Answer (score 1):

Your include path is set to:

> . (relative to current directory)
>   /usr/lib/php
>   /usr/local/lib/php
>   ../library'

Since your "forms" folder is not directly under any of the above include paths that include command won't work.

To fix this, add the /application/ directory to your include path and try again.

Answer (score 1):

As Shane said, you should include your "application" folder in your include path. This should be done in your "index.php" bootstrap file :

```
set_include_path(
    '/paht/to/application' 
    . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path()
);
```

Moreover, you can tell Zend Framework to autoload all classes by adding this to your bootstrap file :

```
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
```

This will save you from having to load manuall each class you use.